# Is there an algorithm for solving systems of nonlinear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, algorithms, computer-algebra-systems

I have many equations of this form:

$cf+ce-bg-ag=j$

$af+ch-dg-be=l$

$cj=j$

$aj+cl=l$

$cm+cn-ao-bo=n$

$an+cp-do-bm=p$

$gj=n$

$ej+gl=p$

I would like to make a computer program to solve systems of this form, so I need a general algorithm, and not some heuristics. If it helps, the summands on the left side of the equations will always be a product of at most two variables, and the summands on the right hand side will always be a product of at most one variable.

Comment: please use tex! what are your variables what are the constants?

Comment: I Tex'd it! They're all variables. I need any particular solution (it has to fulfill some other requirements but I can program that part manually)

Comment: "They're all variables. I need any particular solution" Fantastic! Set them all to zero.

Comment: Well I suppose I will list the other conditions here then.

None of the variables on the right side may be 0, and at least one of each of these sets must be nonzero:

(a,b,c,d) (e,f,g,h), (i,j,k,l), (m,n,o,p)

Comment: You can easily reformulate the system as a nonlinear optimization problem by casting $l.h.s = r.h.s.$ as $F = \|l.h.s - r.h.s\|^2$ and then searching for the arguments that minimize the function. If there is a solution, then the minimum should approach 0 over iterations.